# Web (PHP) application deployment strategy

Tags: php, git, build, continuous-integration

I m thinking about right deployment strategy for PHP (or any) web application.

I have versioned code (git) which contains source codes like LESS, non minified JavaScript etc.

As ideal steps I see this ones:

1. Build app to `/build` directory - including compile LESS, minify JavaScript and others. In build directory will be everything ready for deployment.
2. Run other necessary scripts like tests etc. in /build directory

After this steps I'm a bit confused what to do next.

Whole `/build` directory should be copied to staging/production server, but before I was actually building app I've used to copy only files which changed from last Git commit. Copying all files seems to be inefficient for me. However versioning `/build` directory doesn't seem to be right thing as well.

Other possibility is to create `/build` directory but it seems to be too messy to have built and non built files together and all versioned.

How do you build and deploy web applications?

Comment: You can backup your build directory on each build. Create the new build. Then you can use rsync or diff to find out which files have changed versus the backup build directory if you only want to copy those.

Comment: I think this is rather too broad - there are loads of different ways to build, depending on whether you are hosting in the cloud or a VPS, what build steps your application has, etc. It might be better to pick a specific build technology, fail with it, and ask a specific question about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Jenkins/Hudson CI then you can use different publish plugins which may be executed after successful build. Most of plugins allow you to say exactly what you want to be published and over what protocol.

Basically you run full build on Jenkins, then deliver your build files and artifacts to production server.

Look at [Publish Over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) or [Publish Over FTP](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+FTP+Plugin). Both plugins allow you to configure "Transfer Set" and if you uncheck "Clean remote" checkbox then plugins will only send out files that are different from your production host.

PS: I made an assumption that you use CI server of some sort given tag "continuous-integration"

Comment: Thanks, this could work, but I think, this plugins have to check each file over FTP to see if there is change or not (and not sure if it can delete file which I had deleted from last build). If there are thousands of files on production server, this isnt probably fast solution.. or is it?

Comment: Rest assured countless number of people using these plugins and they are EFFICIENT! Publish Over FTP gets file list over FTP and checks sizes/modification dates. It also may keep information locally on Jenkins to find out which files should be copied and which not (of course you have an option to force full deployment if remote files are out of sync).